# Do we need to call cache for single action?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

For example, i got one spark session and this session only contains one action and lots of transformations. And no partition will failed during the task executets. So does `cache` is unnecessary in this case ? Because cache is used for share rdd between actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pretty much answered your own question.

`cache` will only get into effect after at least one action is called on the RDD you cached. This means that the entire DAG of the RDD needs to be computed from scratch at least once.

Since you only have one action, `cache` will not do anything. Except eating up your executor memory.

Comment: This is true, but there are some situations where it is possible for a single action to use the same RDD multiple times, for example with a self-join.

Comment: I am not convinced based on the comment. Are you sure? I will check tomorrow.

Comment: @puhlen I agree

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need to call `cache()` in your case.